# Destination table becomes truncated at start of running Kettle script

Tags: database, etl, kettle, data-migration

I have a kettle script that reads from Table A, parses the data then sends them to Table 1 and Table 2. From the whole kettle script, I disabled the branch that populates Table 2 and ran the script; from this, Table 1 is populated. After this I did the other way around to populate the other table (Table2). That is, I disabled the branch that populates Table 1. When the script was running, I noticed that Table1 is being truncated while Table2 is being populated. After the whole migration script has finished, both tables are populated.

I also noticed this 'Truncate Table' flag in the destination table. I just don't understand why the truncation is necessary given that I disabled the branch that runs it. Any explanations for this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The truncation happens when the step is initialized. Regardless of the incoming hop being enabled or disabled, the truncation will always happen. Same happens in steps like Text file output, where a 0 byte file is created when the transformation starts.

Comment: Hi, is there an explanation also as to why after running the script, the data comes back? (Not truncated)

Comment: Something else is writting to the table.